# Razor proxy type error. System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a class User and then another Type UserSpecial with some special user properties.
I pass it in razor to the partial method class to create the UserSpecial form which expects an object of type User Special but i get an error.

```
@model User
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            @Html.Partial("../UserSpecial/_CreateOrEdit", Model.UserSpecial)
            <p class="submit clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

Error i get -

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_AC9DED50C9495788046D6BFA3B90DDFC6AD2884157CF23C91FCB3B7A55F70B18', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'UserSpecial'.

What am i doing wrong here?

From my controller i just pass the current User Object that i have stored in the session state.

Controller -

```
 public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View(userRepository.Current);
        }
```

Here Current is of type "User"

Model -

```
public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
        }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string HomeTown { get; set; }
        public short UserType { get; set; }

        public virtual UserSpecial UserSpecial { get; set; }
    }
```

Model Declaration for _CreateOrEdit is

```
@model UserSpecial
```

Comment: Can you show the code that returns the view and its model?

Comment: What's the `@Model` declaration of `UserSpecial/_CreateOrEdit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea what `userRepository.Current` is but it seems that it doesn't correctly/eagerly load the `UserSpecial` property. Why don't you use view models? Why are you passing domain entity models to your views? That's bad practice. You should define view models that contain only the data that's required by your view and then in your controller action map between your domain models and the corresponding view model which will be passed to the view.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not eagerly loading the UserSpecial Property here in the repository. As it will be null since the user is registering for special privileges. Do i need to include (eagerly load) the property .. even if it will be null. I tired that .. it still did not work.

Comment: As far as using View Models, some of my views just need a single entity for data. When i need multiple entities to form a view i create a viewModel else i just pass the data entity.

Comment: I figured out that i needed to initialize the UserSpecial Object and couldn't pass it as null even when i was trying to create a new one.


    if (userRepository.Current.UserSpecial == null)
                {
                    userRepository.Current.UserSpecial = new UserSpecial();
                }
                return View(userRepository.Current);

Comment: Can you explain why it's bad practice to use an entity as your view model? It's just a data structure as long as lazy loading doesn't come into play. I don't see why it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue is pretty simple:

You should just use a wrapper class (view model) as Darin suggested.

So for example:

(entity domain model):

```
public class MyEntityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

=> put it in a ViewModel (just a stupid wrapper) should result in this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyEntityModel MyEntityModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in the view, u should be able to access the "name" property by doing this

```
<div>
    The entity object's name is "@model.MyEntityModel.Name"
</div>
```

(notice you should not use @model.Name!)