# Convert Sql Statement into Linq for use with C#, Entity Framework, MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I need to convert a sql statement to a linq query.

The code below has my area in question marked -

```
public class MyObjectController : Controller
{
    private EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
    private IObjectRepository objRepo;

    public MyObjectController(IObjectRepository objectRepository)
    {
        objRepo = objectRepository;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Client/MyObject/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true);

            if (currentUser != null && currentUser.ProviderUserKey != null && currentUser.IsApproved)
            {
                var currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

<========HOW TO EXECUTE IN LINQ==================>
             Object result = (from obj in objRepo
                             where obj.ObjId == currentUserId
                             select obj).FirstOrDefault();
<========HOW TO EXECUTE IN LINQ==================>

             return View(result);
            }                
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Just to clarify - I am going for something more like this but I don't know how to get the syntax right:

```
Object myObj = moveRepo.Objects
                    .Where(m => m.ObjectId)
                    .Equals(m => currentUserId)
                return View(myObj);
```

Comment: You are using edmx or code first?

Comment: where clause should be `Where(m=>m.ObjectId == somId)` because it expects an expression that returns a boolean value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using LINQ and I don't see any SQL statement. Probably you want to modify the LINQ statement to work it properly. In your query you need to specify the data context and the table.

```
var result = (from obj in yourDataContext.yourEntity
             where obj.ObjId == currentUserId
             select obj).FirstOrDefault();
```

That query will give you your record if found, null otherwise

Comment: Are you familiar with this error -

Are you familiar with this error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Object_3E186F803589BF82895B10E08C2A9AB68EFA619599418D6EB96585D14874CDC0', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MySite.Domain.Entities.Object]'.

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh, you may check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392022/razor-proxy-type-error-system-data-entity-dynamicproxies or post a new question with complete scenario

Comment: I posted the entire scenario here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238905/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-system-data-entity-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LINQpad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

I've found it to be really useful and is ideal for checking what if your linq is doing what you are used to with SQL.

Comment: This is such an awesome link! Thanks...I only regret that I had to give the answer to the actual answer above (so conflicting). But thank you for referring me to this. ( :

Comment: Are you familiar with this error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Object_3E186F803589BF82895B10E08C2A9AB68EFA619599418D6EB96585D14874CDC0', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MySite.Domain.Entities.Object]'.