# Adding a record to the database based on input passed from a link on another form MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have been using ASP.NET MVC 4 for a while but I have not yet come across a situation where i need to insert a value into the database from a scaffolded Create view which is based on a value passed from another view. I have tried to infer from the Edit view to try and modify my code to work but I have run into a snag. I got an error similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238905/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-system-data-entity-dynamic). Here is my code from the view passing the value

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Allocate", "Create", "Allocation", new { id=item.requestID}, null)
```

this is from the list of requests already in the database from the Index view

here is my code on the controller that is trying to force the Create method to use the ID passed from the link above

```
public ActionResult Create(int id = 0)
{
Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        ViewBag.requestID = new SelectList(db.Requests, "requestID", "requestID", request.requestID);
        return View(request);
}
```

then here is the posting code to the db

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Allocation allocation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Allocations.Add(allocation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.requestID = new SelectList(db.Requests, "requestID", "requestID", allocation.requestID);
        return View(allocation);
    }
```

Basically what I am trying to do is allocate funds to a request made where by the allocation is entered into the db based on the request id. I am trying to prevent the user from choosing the request id from a drop down list. When I run this i get an error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Request_A52006F7570E0448EE323CB36858E4D13EED0BAD958340B32FF166708545DA8C', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BudgetAllocation.Models.Allocation'.
```

If theres anyone out there who can help me out with this please do as soon as you can. I appreciate all the effort offred!!!!!

//EDIT
Here is my Create view

```
@model BudgetAllocation.Models.Allocation

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Allocation</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.requestID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.allocAmount, "Amount")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.allocAmount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.allocAmount)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Allocate" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: show your view please

Comment: Which particular view please?

Comment: `Create View` of your `Create` Action

Comment: @EhsanSajjad please refer to the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your view id **strongly typed** with `BudgetAllocation.Models.Allocation` while in get action of `Create` you are passing object  of type `BudgetAllocation.Models.Request` thats why you are getting the exception.

You have to pass object of type  `BudgetAllocation.Models.Allocation` in Create get action as well because you view is strongly typed to it.

```
public ActionResult Create(int id = 0)
{
Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);

return View(request) // <-------------- here is the mistake

}
```

it should return allocation object, something like this, it is just an example may be you need to do some other thing instead of selecting:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id = 0)
{
Allocation allocation = db.Allocations.Find(x=>x.requestID == id);
ViewBag.requestID = new SelectList(db.Requests, "requestID", "requestID", request.requestID);
return View(allocation);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

you simply need to do like this not return allocaiton object return simply View:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id = 0)
    {
    ViewBag.requestID = new SelectList(db.Requests, "requestID", "requestID", request.requestID);
    return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on that

Comment: your view is dtrongly typed so it only accepts object of type Allocation and in the Create Action you are paissing Request object in the view that why it throws exception that view expects model of type allocation not request

Comment: Okay I understand where you're going with that. But the edit that you have made to your answer suggests that you're trying to retrieve the `requestID` from the `Allocations` table which at that particular moment doesn't exist in the table. please advise on how to pass an object of type `Requests` in the `Create` method

Comment: you cannot actually, your view needs allocation object, request object cannnot be passed to it, for that you need to create new action and new view which you can strongly type to Request model

Comment: @WairimuMurigi i don't understand why are you passing request object??

Comment: Okay. I have a table `Request` where one puts in a request for funds. Then someone else comes to allocate them funds and the allocation history goes into the `Allocation` table. What I am trying to do here is redirect the `Allocate` link to the `Create` view for `Allocation` from the `Index` view of `Requests`. Hence passing the `requestID` with the url so when the allocation is being stored in the DB it stores using the `requestID` and not have the user go to the `Create` view of `Allocations` and choose a `requestID` from a dropdown list.

Comment: ok then you need to `return View()` simply not pass allocation object, no need of it actually

Comment: Okay. When I do this, the error doesn't show anymore but the record isn't inserted in the database. Let me check and see if there's something I am missing.

Comment: you only to do this change in get action not HttpPost one

Comment: it should be posted is model null?

Comment: No or could this `@Html.ActionLink("Allocate", "Create", "Allocation", new { id=item.requestID}, null)` be the problem?

Comment: no it has no relation with that in bebug check after form post if model is posted null

Comment: Meant the Model is not null

Comment: then what's the issue/

Comment: Not sure yet. Let me review my code and check around for some solutions and then I will make a comment.

Comment: Hey, I found where the problem was. Final `Create` method now read like `public ActionResult Create(int id = 0)
        {
            var request = db.Requests.Find(id);
            if (request == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound("The Funding Request With the Stated ID Could Not Be Found!");
            }
            var allocation = new Allocation
            {
                Request = request,
                requestID = request.requestID
            };
            return View(allocation);
        }` I created an Allocation send it to the view. I added `request` to it

Comment: that's what i was saying you and posted in answer that it should return allocation object not request..)

Comment: Yea, guess I was too tired :(