# MVC Identity user Profile extension and accessing properties and methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am a newbie to asp.net and  trying to figure out a small issue and could not get through.

what I am trying is to access additional user profile details and display the first name in mylogin partial page and giving an exception, any help to shed something really appreciated.

```
@
{var manager = new UserManager<MyUser>(new UserStore<MyUser>(new MyDbContext ()));
**var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());**
var myname = currentUser.UserInfo.FirstName;
}
```

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_19A2C4C53E8DE616853C0AA38428987A7CBBC56E57FCCF82F04E81B42A687C20' type to the 'BNTracker.Models.MyUser' type is not valid.

MyUser is already inherited from IdentityUser  and its available under models

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }

}

public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please go through  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392022/razor-proxy-type-error-system-data-entity-dynamicproxies  May be this due to you creating new object as new UserStore<MyUser>(new MyDbContext ())

Comment: Thanks a lot, Removed mydbcontext and my user and used ApplicationUser and IdentityDBContext and it worked.

Comment: public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    }


   

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new        DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfoes { get; set; }
         
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new MyDbContext ())
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```